# Broadcast receiver doesn't work at android 4.2.2

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a problem with broadcast. 
This is my receiver:

```
receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                networkConnection = isDataConnected();

                if(firstUseReceiver) {
                    firstUseReceiver = false;
                    return;
                }

                if(networkConnection){
                    Log.i("VMV", "internet on");
                    if(new CheckInternetConnectionType().checkNetworkSettings(context)){
                        clickConnect(null);
                    }else{
                        MultiFragment mf = getCurrentFragment();
                        if(mf != null) {
                            mf.no3GConnection();
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    Log.i("VMV", "internet of");
                    MultiFragment mf = getCurrentFragment();
                    if(mf != null) {
                        mf.noConnection();;
                    }

                }
            }
        };
```

and I use `registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"));`
to check internet connection. On my samsung galaxy s3 with android 4.3 everything is ok, but on samsung galaxy s4 with android 4.2.2 this solution doesn't work. I debug application and I see that register work but when I disable internet connection onReceive is not called. Any idea why on s3 with android 4.3 work and on s4 with 4.2.2 not?

Comment: did you add `itis name` in your manifest?

Comment: if i register broadcast in activity I must add this in manifest?

Comment: I think so can you try it?

Comment: but how can I add this in manifest? As you can see this is not class?

Comment: @edi233:if you register broadcast receiver programmatically then its not required for you to specify in the manifest

Comment: try adding priority to your broadcast receiver using `intentFilter.setPriority(999);`

Comment: i set priority but no changes

Answer (score 0):

can you try this:

```
<receiver android:name=".class_name" >
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.xx.yy.zzz" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```